# Matched p-element gets lost, tokenize chops my sentences

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a problem which I imagine to be rather simple, but I can't wrap my head around it.

I have a large XML with several `<p facs="001">text</p>` elements. I want to match a template on them, but this deletes my p-elements with attributes, what leads to just plain text.
The file should be tokenized by the "!" and keep the `<p facs="#">...</p>`. It also deletes half of the sentences in my `<p>`, which I don't want as well.

Input:

```
<root>
 <text>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p facs="001">Hello Guys! This is my example! Thanks for your time!</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p facs="002">Some more text! And a little more!</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p facs="003">Here as well! See you later!</p>
        </div>
    </body>
 </text>
</root>
```

My XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* |node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/root/text/body/div/p">
            <xsl:variable name="tokens" select="tokenize(text(),'!')" as="xs:string*"/>
            <xsl:variable name="words" select="remove($tokens, 1)" as="xs:string*"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="1 to xs:integer(floor(count($words) div 1))">
                <xsl:variable name="vIndex" select="(.)" as="xs:integer"/>
                <w><xsl:attribute name="n"
                    select="position()"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($words[$vIndex])"/>
                </w>
            </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My output:

```
 <root>
       <text>
          <body>
            <div>
                   <w n="1">This is my example</w>
                   <w n="2">Thanks for your time</w>
                   <w n="3"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                   <w n="1">And a little more</w>
                   <w n="2"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                   <w n="1">See you later</w>
                   <w n="2"/>
            </div>
          </body>
       </text>
    </root>
```

What I want to have as output:

```
 <root>
       <text>
          <body>
            <div>
                <p facs="001">
                   <w n="1">Hello Guys</w>
                   <w n="2">This is my example</w>
                   <w n="3">Thanks for your time</w>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p facs="002">
                   <w n="1">Some more Text</w>
                   <w n="2">And a little more</w>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p facs="003">
                   <w n="1">Here as well</w>
                   <w n="2">See you later</w>
                </p>
            </div>
          </body>
       </text>
    </root>
```

Also, eventhough not necessary, I would like to know if there is a way to keep the "!" I tokenized by. How can I preserve them?

In short: 
a) I don't want my facs attribute deleted
b) I don't want to lose the first sentence
c) How could I save the character I tokenize by? In this example "!"

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep the `p` elements you would just need to have an `xsl:copy` in its template e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="/root/text/body/div/p">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:variable name="tokens" select="tokenize(text(),'!')" as="xs:string*"/>
        <xsl:variable name="words" select="remove($tokens, 1)" as="xs:string*"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="1 to xs:integer(floor(count($words) div 1))">
            <xsl:variable name="vIndex" select="(.)" as="xs:integer"/>
            <w><xsl:attribute name="n"
                select="position()"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($words[$vIndex])"/>
            </w>
        </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

And then I would just use

```
<xsl:template match="/root/text/body/div/p">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '!')">
            <w n="{position()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></w>
        </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

If you want to keep the exclamation mark you might want to look into `xsl:analyze-string` instead of `tokenize`.

I had some time now to test and it seems we need to exclude pure white space tokens; here is the full code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* |node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/root/text/body/div/p">
       <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '!')[normalize-space()]">
                <w n="{position()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></w>
            </xsl:for-each>
       </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That way the input

```
<root>
 <text>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p facs="001">Hello Guys! This is my example! Thanks for your time!</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p facs="002">Some more text! And a little more!</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p facs="003">Here as well! See you later!</p>
        </div>
    </body>
 </text>
</root>
```

is transformed into the result

```
<root>
   <text>
      <body>
        <div>
            <p facs="001">
               <w n="1">Hello Guys</w>
               <w n="2"> This is my example</w>
               <w n="3"> Thanks for your time</w>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p facs="002">
               <w n="1">Some more text</w>
               <w n="2"> And a little more</w>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p facs="003">
               <w n="1">Here as well</w>
               <w n="2"> See you later</w>
            </p>
        </div>
      </body>
   </text>
</root>
```